# How to cancel a timer.schedule() invocation early

Tags: java, time, timer

I have scheduled a method to run at a certain date in the future; however, there are certain events that may or may not happen before that date that would mean I want to run the method earlier than the specified date; how can I do this? I currently have:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask task = new TaskToRunOnExpriation();
timer.schedule(task, myCalendarObject.getTime());
```

I will have many of these `TimerTask`'s running in my application, stop specific instances of them if a certain even happens?

**EDIT**
I will only ever want to cancel a single `Timer` for a given event, is there a way of managing the identities for the `Timers` such that I can easily find and stop it?

Comment: Tried `timer.cancel()` ?

Comment: How do I identify the appropriate timer though if thousands of these are being started?

Comment: How do you find those timers which you want to stop ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have thousands of them you should use a [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) which will pool threads rather than a Timer which will use one thread per timer.

The ScheduledFutures returned by the executor service when you schedule a task also have a cancel method to cancel the underlying tasks: `future.cancel(true);`.

As for cancelling the right task, you could store the futures in a `Map<String, Future>` so you can access them by name or id for example.

Comment: Is there a typical/sufficient number of threads used by the scheduler for an application requiring a few thousand futures? i.e. `x` for `x` in `ScheduledExecutorServe scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(x);`

Comment: @alh, and I want to underline what @assylias says. `you could store the futures in a Map<String, Future> so you can access them by name or id for example` - this is the common way to store something in a collection if you want to take control on it when you want. if you meet problems with identifying your stack, which itme to close, you've choose wrong architecture of your app. try to reconsider things. Usually you make a colltcion with custom classes extended from basic class, where you add a functionality to indentify elements in that way which you want

Comment: @alh try to think of how many tasks could run in parallel and use that number + a small buffer (unless that results in too high a number - you probably don't want say 100 threads - but it very much depends on your use case).

Answer (score 0):

In C# I would say use delegates, but that is not an option in Java. I would work off this idea:

```
class Timers
{
    Timer timer1;
    Timer timer2;
    ArrayList<Timer> timerList;

    public Timers()
    {
        // schedule the timers
    }

    // cancel timers related to an event
    public void eventA()
    {
        timer1.cancel();
        timer2.cancel();
    }

    public void eventB()
    {
        for(Timer t : timerList)
            t.cancel();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this schedule method.

public void schedule(TimerTask task,Date firstTime,long period)

task--This is the task to be scheduled.

firstTime--This is the first time at which task is to be executed.

period--This is the time in milliseconds between successive task executions

Comment: OP wants to cancel timers not schedule them.

Answer (score 0):

I use Timer in android to update a progress bar.Here is some of my code, hoping it can help you:

```
Timer timer ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //....

        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                updateLogoBarHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                Log.e("SplashActivity","updating the logo progress bar...");
         }}, 0, 50);

       //.....

}

//here do the timer.cancel();
private Handler updateLogoBarHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if(logobarClipe.getLevel() < 10000){
                logobarClipe.setLevel(logobarClipe.getLevel() + 50);  
        }else{
                timer.cancel();
        }  
        super.handleMessage(msg);
   }
};
```